# Perl grep two arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, grep

I have one array filled with short strings (@pos), and a second larger array (@exome). I want to search the second array for any match with strings from the first. The goal is to print all  lines from @exome that have a match

Im using perl this is what I have so far

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $pos = $ARGV[0];
my $exome = $ARGV[1];

open (F, "$pos") || die "Could not open $pos: $!\n";
my @pos = <F>;
close F;

open (F, "$exome") || die "Could not open $exome: $!\n";
my @exome = <F>;
close F;

foreach (@pos) {
    my @out = grep(/$_/, @exome);
    print @out
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JoeFrambach: That is not a question. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought @ikegami has given out a quite good answer, BUT, he seems to get mistakes in what array to print...Maybe @user2249959 wants the @exome array to print...
The core code needed is no more than two lines:

```
my $grep_pos = join '|', @pos;
my @matched_results = grep { /$grep_pos/ } @exome;
```

Well, you can print out immediately at the second line, but there won't have a blank space between the elements in the array.
Two foreach loops doesn't look like Perl, just in my own opinion...

P.S. I added three points to pay attention
1. Be careful of the invisible "\n" or "\r\n"
2. Be careful of the white space at the beginning and ending of each string.
You can solve the above two points with simple codes, for example:

```
map { chomp; s/^\s*|\s*$// } @pos;
```

This will delete the "\n"(if have), and white spaces in front or at end(if you assume that  meaningless). Do it before grep
3. MORE IMPORTANT! Be careful of the **blank lines** in the @pos array file!
If your file looks like this:

```
pos_1
pos_2
 <---- totally blank
pos_3
```

If you still join the lines together with '|', it will become 'pos_1|pos_2||pos_3', it means anything in @exome will match. (because of the '**||**')
chomp or s/// won't help, you got to jump this line by yourself
Just be careful :)

Comment: Thank you. But this seems not to work if there are any characters after the string thats matched

eg

pos:
1234

exome:
1234AB

Would not match. AB1234 would. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2249959, Maybe I know what happened. Here is my guess: Do you read the array pos and exome from a file? Then the 1234 should actually be like "1234\n", it contains an invisible character at its tail. So "1234AB\n" will not match, but "AB" added at head ("AB1234\n") still matches "1234\n". I will modify my code as well, as I found a very insteresting error.

Comment: @noalac, why do blank lines comes in the array? How are these blank elements created?

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

- `/$_/` means `$_ =~ /$_/`, so perhaps you should use a different variable for the pattern.
- You don't convert the text to a regex pattern (which can be done using `quotemeta`)
- It's possible for you to output the same line twice.
- Please don't use global vars for file handles.
- No need loading the entire file being searched into memory.

Solution:

```
my ($pos_qfn, $exome_qfn) = @ARGV;

open(my $pos_fh, '<', $pos_qfn)
   or die("Could not open $pos_qfn: $!\n");
my @pos = <$pos_fh>;
chomp(@pos);

my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @pos;

open(my $exome_fh, '<', $exome_qfn)
   or die("Could not open $exome_qfn: $!\n");

while (<$exome_fh>) {
   print if /$pat/;
}
```

Comment: I think your code is compiling matching pattern in each invocation. Simply adding `$pat = qr/$pat/;` after join should solve the problem.